# How to use CSS to create the left - right alignment so the left div does not push the right div

Tags: html, css

I do not do much of `css` but I need to design a template using `html`. The template will be used to display data later on. I need to create the correct layout.

I need to have Left Div - `<div id="toAddress"></div>` 
and Right Div - `<div id="fromAddress"></div>`.

After `<div id="toAddress"></div>` I have another `div` element with `id="des"`.

When `<div id="des">` is inserted, it pushes `<div id="fromAddress"></div>` toward button. How can I align my page the right way, so, all 3 `div` elements are aligned?

I have the following html file:

```
<body>
    <div id = "pageName">
        REQUEST
    </div>
    <div id = "toAddress">
        <table>
            <tr><td>To:</td><td id="toName">Company</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Fax:</td><td id="toFax">Uknown</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Date:</td><td>04 Jun 2001 10:30:21</td></tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div id="des">
        Long Text iferkjfklrejfkl;lgkbl'hgknl'knhjlpnhjjhpjtrjgitojgiotrgiotrgotriotr            lmnjhpjmljhpjlopjljpjjop[kkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkk;khgpoopoyuiyuiyuiyiuyiyiyuiyiu
    </div>
    <div id = "fromAddress">
            <table>
                <tr><td id="from">From:</td>
                    <td>
                        <table>
                            <tr><td>Company</td></tr>
                            <tr><td>Office</td></tr>
                            <tr><td>100 Bond Street</td></tr>
                            <tr><td>London</td></tr>
                            <tr><td>W1</td></tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                <tr><td>Fax:</td><td id="fromFax">0207 234567890/</td>            </tr>
                <tr><td>Tel:</td><td id="fromTel">0207 123456789/</td></tr>
            </table>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

My css file is the following:

```
#pageName
{
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: underline;
}

#toAddress
{
    float:left;
    margin-left:20px;
}

#fromAddress
{
    float:right;
    margin-right:100px;
}

#from
{
    vertical-align:top;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-right: 5px;
}

#des
{
   width:730px;
   margin-top: 80px;
   margin-left:5px;
}
```

Final template should look like the following image:

[image]

What is the right way to do that? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<body>
    <div id = "pageName">
        REQUEST
    </div>
    <div id = "toAddress">
        <table>
            <tr><td>To:</td><td id="toName">Company</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Fax:</td><td id="toFax">Uknown</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Date:</td><td>04 Jun 2001 10:30:21</td></tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div id = "fromAddress">
            <table>
                <tr><td id="from">From:</td>
                    <td>
                        <table>
                            <tr><td>Company</td></tr>
                            <tr><td>Office</td></tr>
                            <tr><td>100 Bond Street</td></tr>
                            <tr><td>London</td></tr>
                            <tr><td>W1</td></tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                <tr><td>Fax:</td><td id="fromFax">0207 234567890/</td>            </tr>
                <tr><td>Tel:</td><td id="fromTel">0207 123456789/</td></tr>
            </table>
    </div>
    <div id="des">
        Long Text iferkjfklrejfkl;lgkbl'hgknl'knhjlpnhjjhpjtrjgitojgiotrgiotrgotriotr            lmnjhpjmljhpjlopjljpjjop[kkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkk;khgpoopoyuiyuiyuiyiuyiyiyuiyiu
    </div>
</body>
```

I moved `#fromAddress` to follow immediatly after `#toAddress`, I hope that's in the format you are looking for, heres a demo:

[CODEPEN DEMO](http://codepen.io/Gothburz/pen/bVxjNX/)

Comment: Thank you. That's what I needed. Also, by any chance, do you know how to design the table on the picture? I created the table, but cannot figure out how to hide the border from 1st to 8th column